# Assigning multiple divisions (DIV) in CSS and linking to HTML

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to assign CSS styles to multiple HTTP divisions. The first division (#CSU) works and displays the desired CSS styles. However, the following divisions (#TAFE2021, #TAFE2020 etc) do not show CSS styles. I have attempted both internal and external CSS.

I post two files below; first file is the HTML file. Second File is the CSS file.

```css
h1 {
  color: #0000FF;
}

h2 {
  color: #0000FF;
}

h3 {
  color: #0000FF;
}

#CSU {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: left;
  #TAFE2021 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 500px;
    border: 15px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    Float: left;
    #TAFE2020 {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      Float: left;
    }
    #TAFE2019A {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      Float: left;
    }
    #TAFE2019B {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      Float: left;
    }
    #TAFE2019C {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      Float: right;
    }
    #TAFE2018A {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      Float: right;
    }
    #TAFE2018B {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      Float: right;
    }
    #TAFE2017 {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 500px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
      Float: right;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>
    Shane Curries Resume in HTML
  </TITLE>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Edcuation\CSS\Edcuation.css" />

</HEAD>

<BODY Background="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Contact\Photos\background.png">
  <A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\index.html">index</A>
  <H1>
    <center>
      Education
    </center>
  </H1>
  <br>
  <img src="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Edcuation\Photos\cpu.jpg" width=351 Height=470 ALT="CPU">
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="CSU">
    <h3>2021 - ongoing</h3>
    <h3>Charles Sturt University</h3>
    <br>
    <LI>TC133 _ Customer Support Managerment

  </div>
  <br>


  <div id="TAFE2021">

    <h3>2021 - ongoing</h3>
    <h3>TAFE NSW</h3>
    <h3>Diploma of Information Networking</h3>
    <UL>
      <LI>ICTNWK506 Configure, verify and troubleshoot WAN links and IP services in a medium enterprise network
        <br>
        <LI>ICTNWK507 Install, operate and troubleshoot medium enterprise routers
          <br>
          <LI>ICTNWK508 Install, operate and troubleshoot medium enterprise switches
            <br>
            <LI>ICTNWK505 Design, build and test a network server
              <br>
              <LI>ICTSUS501 Implement server virtualisation for a sustainable ICT system
                <br>
                <LI>ICTTEN514 Install, configure and test a server
                  <br>
                  <LI>ICTICT418 Contribute to copyright, ethics and privacy in an ICT environment
                    <br>
                    <LI>ICTICT509 Gather data to identify business requirements
                      <br>
                      <LI>ICTICT517 Match ICT needs with the strategic direction of the organisation
                        <br>
                        <LI>ICTNWK503 Install and maintain valid authentication processes
                          <br>
                          <LI>ICTNWK529 Install and manage complex ICT networks
                            <br>
                            <LI>ICTPMG501 Manage ICT projects
                              <br>
                              <LI>ICTTEN611 Produce an ICT network architecture design
                                <br>
    </UL>

  </div>




  <div id="TAFE2020">

    <h3>2020</h3>
    <h3>TAFE NSW</h3>
    <h3>ICT40418 Cert IV in Information Technology Networking </h3>


    <UL>
      <LI>ICTNWK403 Manage network and data integrity
        <br>
        <LI>ICTNWK421 Install, configure and test network security
          <br>
          <LI>ICTTEN417 Install, configure and test a router
            <br>
            <LI>ICTTEN419 Implement and troubleshoot enterprise routers and switches
              <br>
              <LI>ICTNWK404 Install, operate and troubleshoot a small enterprise branch network
                <br>
                <LI>ICTTEN420 Design, install and configure an internetwork
                  <br>
                  <LI>ICTNWK401 Install and manage a server
                    <br>
                    <LI>ICTTEN416 Install, configure and test an internet protocol network
                      <br>
                      <LI>ICTNWK409 Create scripts for networking
                        <br>
                        <LI>ICTNWK405 Build a small wireless local area network
                          <br>
                          <LI>ICTNWK408 Configure a desktop environment
                            <br>
                            <LI>ICTICT418 Contribute to copyright, ethics and privacy in an ICT environment
                              <br>
                              <LI>ICTNWK412 Create network documentation
                                <br>
                                <LI>ICTNWK411 Deploy software to networked computers
                                  <br>
                                  <LI>ICTICT401 Determine and confirm client business requirements
                                    <br>
                                    <LI>ICTNWK420 Install and configure virtual machines
                                      <br>
                                      <LI>BSBWHS304 Participate effectively in WHS communication and consultation processes
                                        <br>
    </UL>

  </div>

  <div id="TAFE2019A">

    <h3>2019</h3>
    <h3>TAFE NSW</h3>
    <h3>ICT40418 Cert III in Information Technology Networking </h3>

    <ul>
      <LI>ICTSAS305 - Provide ICT advice to clients
        <br>
        <LI>ICTICT302 - Install and optimise operating system software
          <br>
          <LI>ICTSAS308 - Run standard diagnostic tests
            <br>
            <LI>ICTPRG301 - Apply introductory programming techniques
              <br>
              <LI>ITCNWK302 - Determine and action network problems
                <br>
                <LI>ICTNWK304 - Administer network peripherals
                  <br>
                  <LI>ICTNWK305 - Install and manage network protocols
                    <br>
                    <LI>ICTSAS307 - Install, configure and secure a small office or home office network
                      <br>
                      <LI>ICTICT303 - Connect internal hardware components
                        <br>
                        <LI>ICTSAS303 - Care for computer hardware
                          <br>
                          <LI>ICTSAS304 - Provide basic system administration
                            <br>
                            <LI>ICTSAS306 - Maintain equipment and software
                              <br>
    </UL>

  </div>

  <div id="TAFE2019B">

    <h3>2019</h3>
    <h3>TAFE NSW</h3>
    <h3>Community Services IV</h3>

    <ul>
      <LI>Facilitate the interests and rights of clients
        <br>
        <LI>Assess co-existing needs
          <br>
          <LI>Provide individualised support
            <br>
            <LI>Work within a community development framework
              <br>
              <LI>Use communication to build relationships
                <br>
                <LI>Recognise and respond appropriately to domestic and family violence
                  <br>
                  <LI>Work with diverse people
                    <br>
                    <LI>Work legally and ethically
                      <br>
                      <LI>Coordinate client directed services
                        <br>
                        <LI>Work with people with mental health issues
                          <br>
                          <LI>Develop and maintain networks and collaborative partnerships
                            <br>
                            <LI>Identify and respond to children and young people at risk
                              <br>
                              <LI>Work with people experiencing or at risk of homelessness
                                <br>
                                <LI>Maintain work health and safety
                                  <br>
                                  <LI>Engage respectfully with young people
                                    <br>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div id="TAFE2019C">

    <h3>2019</h3>
    <h3>TAFE NSW</h3>
    <h3>Business Administration IV</h3>

    <ul>
      <LI>Use business technology
        <br>
        <LI>Organise meetings
          <br>
          <LI>Organise business travel
            <br>
            <LI>Design and develop complex text documents
              <br>
              <LI>Develop and use complex spreadsheets
                <br>
                <LI>Make a presentation
                  <br>
                  <LI>Write complex documents
                    <br>
                    <LI>Analyse and present research information
                      <br>
                      <LI>Administer projects
                        <br>
                        <LI>Promote products and services
                          <br>
                          <LI>Design and produce text documents
                            <br>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div id="TAFE2018A">

    <h3>2018</h3>
    <h3>TAFE NSW</h3>
    <h3>Business Administration III</h3>

    <ul>
      <LI>Develop keyboarding speed and accuracy
        <br>
        <LI>Contribute to health and safety of self and others
          <br>
          <LI>Organise schedules
            <br>
            <LI>Create electronic presentations
              <br>
              <LI>Design and produce text documents
                <br>
                <LI>Produce spreadsheets
                  <br>
                  <LI>Produce desktop published documents
                    <br>
                    <LI>Write simple documents
                      <br>
                      <LI>Process customer complaints
                        <br>
                        <LI>Deliver and monitor a service to customers
                          <br>
                          <LI>Use business technology
                            <br>
                            <LI>Create and use databases
                              <br>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div id="TAFE2018B">

    <h3>2018</h3>
    <h3>TAFE NSW</h3>
    <h3>Foundation Skills Support</h3>

    <ul>
      <LI>Identify & use whole numbers ,simple fractions, decimals, percentages
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div id="TAFE2017">

    <h3>2017</h3>
    <h3>TAFE VIC</h3>
    <h3>MTM20111 - Certificate II in Meat Processing</h3>

    <ul>
      <LI>Abattoir Duties
        <br>
        <LI>Lifestock Processing

  </div>


  <br><br>
  <A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\index.html">go back</A>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: That does not look like CSS syntax but of a pre-processor. Or are you missing `}` after the classes just like you did with h1, h2 and h3?

Comment: Yeah, I missed the dam "}" Thanks for noticing that.  Feel free to answer the question so you get your points.

Comment: Suggestion: Since they're all using the same styles, you can create just one class and reuse it rather than assigning the same rules to each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use IDE for coding.
in this case you forget to close bracket `}` end of the #CSU and #TAFE2021. close that bracket .

I edited in this :

```css
h1 {
  color: #0000FF;
}

h2 {
  color: #0000FF;
}

h3 {
  color: #0000FF;
}

#CSU {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: left;
}

#TAFE2021 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: left;
}

#TAFE2020 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: left;
}

#TAFE2019A {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: left;
}

#TAFE2019B {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: left;
}

#TAFE2019C {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: right;
}

#TAFE2018A {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: right;
}

#TAFE2018B {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: right;
}

#TAFE2017 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  border: 15px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  Float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first thing that sticks out to me: You have an unclosed li tag in your first div. That’s why none of the other styles are rendering.

Some additional notes:

- It is not super common to capslock your tags, but it’s especially strange to caps lock only specific tags. HEAD and BODY are probably fine but stuff like LI will make your code harder to read and understand when mixed in with lowercase tags.
- I’m not a fan of using br. Seeing as you clearly have some basic CSS knowledge, I’d recommend removing the 
   tags and add classes to your elements with margin/padding properties to allow you to space them better.
- Make more CSS classes, and assign multiple classes to elements by using spaces like

```
<li class=“list-item job-title BGRed”>University of College</li>
```

That’ll save you a lot of work tweaking it because you won’t have to repeatedly type out changes to css styles which are used in multiple places.

If you have any other questions, feel free to hmu. I took a 7 month bootcamp on Web Development and am going into a different field. So I’d be more than happy to put that knowledge to use lol.

Comment: I have only been studying CSS today, but starting to get a better understanding of it I will study up more on CSS Classes and Elements

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of curly quotes. You need to replace the `“` with `"`